# Why is value returned before asynchronous call is resolved, even when using async/await?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous

The following function returns the Promise before `this.codesService.getCostCodes()` resolves, resulting in undefined

```
  async getTopParentByChildId(id: string) {
    let parent;

    await this.codesService.getCostCodes().subscribe( data => {
      parent = data.body[0];
    });

    return new Promise<BidItem>(resolve => {           //returning `parent` results in the same issue
      resolve(parent);
    });

  }
```

`getTopParentByChildId()` is being called by another asynchronous function that has the same issue where it returns undefined before resolving the async call:

```
  async populateBidItemObjectArray(node){
    const parent = await this.getTopParentByChildId(node.id);    //should wait for function to return before executing the rest

    const bidItem = {
      name: parent.name,
      id: parent.id
    };

    return new Promise<BidItem>(resolve => {     //returns undefined before this.getTopParentByChildId is resolved
      resolve(parent);
    });
  }
```

I've read a lot about async/await and promises, but none of the solutions I've tried have worked for me so far. I'm unable to understand why it's not waiting for the async functions to resolve when I'm using the async/await keywords.

Comment: You can `await` a `Promise` and that is it. You can't await a rxjs subscription (or even an rxjs observable which would have made more sense to try).

Comment: There's no point in using `new Promise` here. You would want to do `return Promise.resolve(parent)`, but even that is unnecessary - in the `async function`, you can just write `return parent;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `await` a `Promise` and that is it. You can't await a rxjs subscription (or even an rxjs observable which would have made more sense to try but still won't work).

You can refactor `getTopParentByChildId` to this which removes the async/await as they are not needed.

```
getTopParentByChildId(id: string) {
  return this.codesService.getCostCodes()
    .pipe(map(data => data.body[0]))
    .toPromise();
}
```

You can refactor `populateBidItemObjectArray` to this.

```
populateBidItemObjectArray(node) {
  return this.getTopParentByChildId(node.id)
    .then(_ => {
      return {
          name: _.name,
          id: _.id
        };
    });
}
```